# Pushing information from an array to a different nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Currently, I have `dataArray`, which goes on and on with different pieces of information for each object key. I'm trying to move some pieces to the nested arrays within `scndArray` and `thrdArray`:

```
var dataArray = {
    'data':     [{
        'datum1': '',
        'datum2': '',
        'datum3': '',
        'datum4': '',
        'datum5': '',
        'datum6': '',
        'datum7': '',
        'datum8': '',
    }, {
        'datum1': '',
        'datum2': '',
        'datum3': '',
        'datum4': '',
        'datum5': '',
        'datum6': '',
        'datum7': '',
        'datum8': '',
    }]
};

var scndArray = [
    [ ['datum8', 'datum3'] ],
    [ ['datum8', 'datum3'] ]
    ];
var thrdArray = [
    [ ['datum2', 'datum1'] ],
    [ ['datum2', 'datum1'] ]
];
```

I'm trying to use the `.push` function to move these pieces of information but am running into trouble because I need to move the info to the third levels of each array.

```
scndArray.push({datum8, datum3});
thrdArray.push({datum2, datum1});
```

Am I going about this the right way or is there a better/different way to do this?

Comment: Can you briefly clarify exactly what you are intending to do? You would like to move some data from the `dataArray` into a new array?

Comment: Yeah, I have the data in `dataArray` and want to move some selective parts of it to the third levels of `scndArray` and `thrdArray`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create the inner arrays first then insert into the main array?

```
var temp = [];
temp.push([ datum8, datum3 ]);
scndArray.push(temp);

var temp2 = [];
temp.push([ datum2, datum1 ]);
thrdArray.push(temp2);
```